# unknown option "-browsecmd" at /usr/lib/perl5/Tk/Widget.pm line 205?

Tags: perl, arguments, tk-toolkit

**note:** I'm using Perl/Tk on Perl 5

I'm working on a new application, to find this error message:

```
unknown option "-browsecmd" at /usr/lib/perl5/Tk/Widget.pm line 205.
at pack2.pl line 76
```

Here is the full argument:

```
$f1->Checkbutton(-text => "-expand", -onvalue => 1, -offvalue => 0,
    -variable => \$expand[$count], -browsecmd => \&repack)
    ->pack(-ipady => 5, -side => 'left');
```

What did I do wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: Please let us know which subversion of Perl 5 you are using. Perl v5.0 was release eighteen years ago, while Perl v5.16 appeared in May this year. There are many differences! Also, you don't seem to be very good at accepting the answers that have helped you. Please check your previous question about `Perl/Tk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-browsecmd` option is generally available only for list, tree or grid widgets, where the user can select one of a number of options.

If you want to execute a callback when a checkbutton is clicked then you want the `-command` option.